# How many wiring combinations exist for an n-pin cable/connector?

Tags: connector, wiring, math, obfuscation

This is more a pedantic question about the possible number of wiring permutations inherent to an *n*-pin connector and cable.  Note *combinations* imply that elements may be used more than once (combined), whereas *permutations* do not.

I occasionally have to fabricate custom cables for esoteric devices or troubleshoot them (example cable cut or missing, service manual unavailable, etc.)  On a four or nine-pin connector, this isn't a problem because the number of permutations is very low, some pins are unused or are otherwise identifiable, or the connector follows some standard.  But what about a 16-pin touchpad connector, where all pins are used and none have a definite, identifiable function?  **How many wiring permutations exist for this connector?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer involves the vast mathematical field of [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).

If we consider the [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) formula, \$_nP_k\$ or \$P(n,k)\$, which is to say "*k-permutations of n*", *n* is the "total number of elements" and *k* is the "sample size."

$$ _nP_k = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} $$

This formula is specifically for permutations, where elements are *not* duplicated and element order *matters*. For our purposes, we can say *n* is the total number of pins, and *k* is the used number of pins. So calculating for ordered permutation, with no duplication of 16/16 pins:

$$ _nP_k = \frac{16!}{(16-16)!} $$
$$ _nP_k = \frac{16!}{0!} $$
$$ _nP_k = \frac{16!}{1} $$
$$ _nP_k = 16! $$
$$ _nP_k = 16\times 15\times 14 \ldots \times 3\times 2\times 1 $$
$$ _nP_k \approx 20.9\times 10^{12} $$

The [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of 0 is 1. So there are almost 21 trillion ways in which the wires could be re-ordered in a 16-pin cable/connector.

---

If we wanted to *allow* duplicate elements (repetition) of a permutation, where order does *not* matter, this is termed a *Combination*.  This is also known as the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) of \$n\$, \$\binom {n}{k}\$, a *k-selection*, a *k-multiset*, or a *k-combination with repetition*.  The combination formula is:
$$ _nC_k = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} $$
This formula is slightly different from the permutation formula to account for the duplicate elements.  The duplicates reduce the number of available combinations, so are factored into the bottom half of the equation.

Ex: a 16-pin connector, all pins of which are used, but the cable only has nine wires. How many unique combinations exist?

Ans: 11,440.

---

If we wanted to *allow* duplicate elements (repetition) of a permutation, where order *does* matter, the formula is:
$$ n^k $$
Where \$n\$ is the range of elements to choose from, and \$k\$ is how many elements are chosen. This (permutation with repetition of \$n\$ chosen elements) is not really a permutation formula at all; it is known as an *"n-tuple"*.

Ex: How many values are possible on a digital cable, where each digit ranges from 0-2 (tri-state), and 13 wires are used?

Ans: \$ 3^{13} \$ = 1,594,323

Comment: Good answer , but there was once a cable tester we used in production that could test all permutations by simultaneously sending unique signals down each path to verify go, no go in 1 test if Ok then by correlation, report the open or short to any other wire in very few tests instantly.

Comment: True, but in that case the tester performs one test and determines that pin 1 on one end is connected to pin n on the other end, and so the ‘tree’ of 16! permutations can be pruned heavily.  It’s quite right that the actual pin out can be identified without having to test every permutation.

Answer (score 3):

There are 16 possibilities for connecting the first wire; when that one has been connected, there are 15 possibilities left for the second wire, after which there are 14 possibilities left for the third wire, and so on to the last wire, which can only be connected in one way once all other wires have been connected.

This means the number of permutations is:

16 × 15 × 14 × ... × 2 × 1 = 16!

16! is 20,922,789,888,000 or about 20.9 · 10<sup>12</sup>.